# Is there any easy way to run jetty 8 from gradle (like with jettyRun)?

Tags: scala, maven-2, jetty, gradle, maven-jetty-plugin

Unlucky I need jetty 8 to work properly with spray/akka (it's scala project).
 
With older version used by jettyRun I'm getting error like:
 *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/ContinuationListener* 

Is it possible to create some simple task to do the job which jettyRun is doing but with jetty 8?

In worst case I can use embedded version of jetty with war which I'm building, but I would be happy to see some simpler solution if there is any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find good solution at the gradle build level I decided to use embedded jetty. Here is scala class:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector

object JettyServer {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server = new Server
    val context = new WebAppContext
    val connector = new SocketConnector

    connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60)
    connector.setPort(8080)

    context.setServer(server)
    context.setWar(args(0))

    server.setConnectors(Array(connector))
    server.setHandler(context)

    try {
      server.start();
      server.join();
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And then in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.mycompany.myproject"
run.args = [war.archivePath]
task jettyRun(dependsOn: run)
```

And everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

Pitor, why didn't you end up adding your excellent answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266311/how-to-run-jetty-7-with-specified-war-with-groovy-gradle#answer-8458191)?

I've adapted it below, to use Jetty version `9`, to depend on the `war` task, and to use the same task name as the jetty plugin (i.e. `jettyRun`).

```
configurations {
    jetty
}

dependencies {
    jetty "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-runner:9.2.11.v20150529"
}

task jettyRun(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: war) {
    main = "org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner"
    args = [war.archivePath]
    classpath configurations.jetty
}
```

#### Usage:

```
gradle jettyRun
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little late for an answer :) But I'll post it for others who would google around for the same thing.

I stumbled upon the same issue while trying to run a scalatra app with gradle.
I found this plugin and it just works - https://github.com/martins1930/jettyMulti